# SQLSERVER 2008 Login failed for user '(null)'. Reason: Not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am using `SQL SERVER 2008 R2` and I have a job which runs a DTS daily. When I try to execute the DTS package it works but when I try to use the scheduled job it returns the error:

**Error**:

```
-2147467259 (80004005); Provider Error:  18452 (4814)      Error string:  Login failed for user '(null)'. Reason: Not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.      Error source:  Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server      Help file:        Help context:  0.  Process Exit Code 1.  The step failed.
```

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps:

```
1. Start > Programs > Microsoft SQL Server 2008 > SQL Server Management Studio. 
2. In the Object Explorer, right-click the Server and select Properties. 
3. In the Server Properties dialog box select the Security page. 
4. Under Server authentication, select SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode.
```

Then restart the server.

For further reference check [this.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsz5788z.aspx)

Comment: Change the Authentication Mode of the SQL server from `Windows Authentication Mode (Windows Authentication)` to `Mixed Mode (Windows Authentication and SQL Server Authentication)`.

Comment: it is marked so in management studio and I set the owner of the job to sa. what could be missing ?!

Comment: Check http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/01/17/sql-server-fix-login-failed-for-user-username-the-user-is-not-associated-with-a-trusted-sql-server-connection-microsoft-sql-server-error-18452/

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this issue and spent lot of time.
Finally found the issue is not in any user settings but my publish settings are overriding my connection string.

In web deploy settings there is an option to override your web.config connection string. Either untick that option or place the correct connection string.

For more details see this post https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/141243

I am placing this answer in case anyone gets stuck like me. :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. But anyway, your answer is more than appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks for your review koceeng. Edited my answer :)